# Removing templates set in PHP files

Tags: magento2, php, blocks, template

What is the best practice for removing template files that have been defined in PHP files?

For example I want to remove `helper/summary_short.phtml` on category pages, normally I'd remove the block via XML. But I can't do this as the template isn't defined in a block, it's defined in PHP.

### **vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/ReviewRenderer.php**

```
/**
     * Array of available template name
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_availableTemplates = [
        self::FULL_VIEW => 'helper/summary.phtml',
        self::SHORT_VIEW => 'helper/summary_short.phtml',
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out right after finishing the question, the template is also called within `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` - line 72.

```
<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
```

I removed this in my own template file successfully removed the template - `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`